# Python - Pandas resample dataframe with strings and floats

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe where the index is a `datetimeindex`, and every row is every day over the course of a couple years. I need to resample the dataframe by month where the two float columns are summed, but the string columns are all the unique values during that month. I can do the resampling to a single column, but I don't know how to do it to everything, or how to combine them back together if I do it one at a time.

For the floats I was trying:

```
# go through the column list
for col in col_list:
    # process all run time columns for month
    if "float" in str(col):
        # resample for one month and sum
        df[col] = df[col].resample('M').sum()
        # rename the column
        df.rename(columns={col: col + " MONTHLY"}, inplace=True)
```

and for the strings:

```
elif "string" in str(col):
    # get all the unique jobs run during the month
    df[col] = df[col].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).unique()
    df.rename(columns={col: col + " MONTHLY"}, inplace=True)
```

these were resulting in the monthly data being inserted into tho the dataframe with every day still existing though, and was hard to find and not what I need.

Some sample data:

```
        float_1 float_2 string_1    string_2
12/30/2019  1   2   a   a
12/31/2019  1   3   a   b
1/1/2020    2   4   a   c
1/2/2020    3   5   b   d
```

The expected output would be:

```
12/2019 2   5   a    a, b
1/2020  5   9   a, b c, d
```

Not sure if it matters but the real data does have NaN in random days throughout the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try aggregate numeric columns and non numeric columns separately and then join them back:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

numerics = df.select_dtypes('number').resample('M').sum()
strings = df.select_dtypes('object').resample('M').agg(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))

numerics.join(strings)
#            float_1  float_2 string_1 string_2
#2019-12-31        2        5        a      a,b
#2020-01-31        5        9      a,b      d,c
```

Comment: That worked pretty well. I don't know why but the `strings` also returned the numeric columns, although combining the strings by month worked. The numeric column worked as intended and returned only the numeric columns summed by month. This was a problem because when joined all the string columns contained `_x`, `_y` columns. Solved with a loop to drop columns containing a list of words represented in all string column names: `strings.drop(list(strings.filter(regex=l)), axis = 1, inplace = True)`. The real dataset has ~80 columns. Thanks for the help!! Good solution.

Comment: Ok, found my problem from the above comment, the `_x` and `_y` thing was my fault. No problems at all with your solution. Thank you.